# Why is iframe DOM access restricted for cross-site usage?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, web, iframe

Today, I was starting to build a trading tool. Luckily, [TradingView.com](https://www.tradingview.com/widget/advanced-chart/) gives you free access, where you can embed charts legally on your website via iframes.

I planned to select a stock symbol within the iframe (see picture: left corner "BTCUSDT") and read the chosen symbol name via javascript.  For example, when I choose "BTCUSDT" (or Bitcoin) I want to fetch this value, so I know which cryptocurrency I want to order by using another API service. I found out that "for security reasons" this is not possible.

However, in the picture you can see that iframe elements can be easily accessed by hand. So, why can't we read them out from javascript as well? What kind of (effective) security breach would that be?

[image]

Well... I can understand that some people might use this for evil phishing purposes but will this effectively stop them? They might use a proxy or other workaround for that. On the other hand, only reading a simple value for a tool meant to be embedded cross-site makes it more complicated than it should be.

Python has a beautiful library called "BeautifulSoup". Here you can enter a URL, and it reads all the DOM elements from a website. I don't understand how this is possible in python but restricted in javascript.

I have found no reasonable answer or solution for these kind of scenarios. If this is meant for higher security, there are many ways to read out those values other than relying on javascript. So why restrict them?

Comment: There's a big difference between the user of the browser being able to "see" things and code from one domain being able to see content from another domain.

Comment: by that you mean javascript allows to read "more" in comparison what the user can see? If so, is there a way to only read the contents that users can "see"? I have been looking around the whole day just to read a string with 7 characters... :(

Comment: "*I don't understand how this is possible in python but restricted in javascript.*" - it's not restricted in javascript as a language, it's restricted in the browser where the user is running someone else's code. You can perfectly write a CLI application in JS does that same as your python script.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking. If you could simply access the DOM of any frame in your page, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting would be trivial.